# HQL size using QueryOver without subquery

Tags: nhibernate

Hope that someone can answer this.

I know that I can do the following using hql (pseudo code below)

```
var hql = "from objectA l where size(l.ChildCollection) > 0";

var data = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
            .List<objectA>();
```

Is there a wondering if you could do something similar using QueryOver. Without resorting to using a sub query.I have a session filter on ChildCollection.

Unfortunately,

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<ObjectA>()
.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ChildCollection).IsNotEmpty();
```

Produces,

```
WHERE
    exists(
        select
            1 
        from
            [ChildCollection] 
        where
            this_.Id=ObjectA_Id
    );
```

Where as the Hql produces,

```
where
(
   select
       count(childcollection1_.ObjectA_Id) 
   from
       [ChildCollection] childcollection1_ 
    where
       objectA0_.Id=childcollection1_.ObjectA_Id 
       and childcollection1_.DTCreated between @p0 and @p1
    )>0
```

Cheers

Tanzy

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<ObjectA>().WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ChildCollection).IsNotEmpty();
```

Both queries will generate similar sql:

```
SELECT this_.Id
FROM   [ObjectA] this_
WHERE  exists(select 1 from [ChildObjectB] where this_.Id = [key])
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: I've edited question as can't fit the information in the comment

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to generate *exactly* the same sql? The `execution plan` in `sql-server` will be identical for both queries

Comment: The ChildCollection has a filter assigned to it, so when using size(ChildCollection) in the HQL it includes the session filter that has been set on its limitation. However, using the QueryOver IsNotEmpty does not use this session filter.